# xamarin android , cannot convert drawable to bitmap from another class

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-drawable

i have a class that converts drawable image (png) to bitmap. in MainActivity i can do that but when i want do it in other classes i cnnot.

```
public class BitModel
    {

        public BitModel()
        {
            var _bit = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(Android.Content.Res.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon);
        }

    }
```

the `Android.Content.Res.Resources` does not resolve that says ***Resources is a type which is not valid in the given context***

Comment: Hey,did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the  constructor with a parameter in the model.

```
public class BitModel
{

    public BitModel(Context context)
    {
        var _bit = BitmapFactory.DecodeResource(context.Resources, Resource.Drawable.Icon);
    }

}
```

And pass the current context as a parameter when you init the model.For example in the `MainActivity`

```
BitModel model =new BitModel(context) // the context is the current context in the activity
```